# Android: compile CI/CD variables and use them in Android project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, continuous-integration, environment-variables

I have keys defined in CI/CD platform like this

[image: CI/CD environment variables]

Is there a way I can compile this variable with my build so that I can reference it in Android project?

The idea is to sign in the user with username and password(saved in CI/CD variables) during UI test cases.